# How do i control my CPU fan for Lenovo ideapad Z710?

Tags: 22.04, cpu, fan, overheating, minecraft

my cpu has been idling at about 60 degrees celcius. and when running Minecraft, it goes up to around 85. this is causing the entire ubuntu 22.04 jammy jellyfish system to freeze until forcefully shut down. i want to be able to make fans run at full all the time because the noise doesn't bother me. how would i do this? i have tried fancontrol and fancontrol-gui and neither worked. i am using a lenovo ideapad Z710 laptop with core i7.